# Is $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I wonder if $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}\times \ldots$ is countable.

I came across this question because I was looking to see if the metric space $(l^1(\mathbb{N}),d_\infty)$ is separable. With $l^1(\mathbb{N})=\{(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n| \ \text{converges} \}$ and $d_\infty((x_n)_n,(y_n)_n)=\sup \{|x_n-y_n| n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. So I thought if $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ is countable than $(l^1(\mathbb{N}),d_\infty)$ is separable. Because then $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ would be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and so $\{(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}|\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n| \ \text{converges} \} $ a countable dense subset of $\{(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}|\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n| \ \text{converges} \} $.

Comment: Are the sequences of ones and zeros countable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: By considering the digits of each real number, we can construct an injective function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clear.

Comment: You probably mean the function to go in the other direction though...

Comment: That’s my fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No.  $|\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}|\ge2^{\aleph_0}\gt \aleph_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

By Cantor's theorem, $|A|\ge2\implies|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}\ge 2^{|B|}>|B|$. In fact, you can show $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ using the upper bound $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$.